# How is JpaTransactionManager envoked

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-data-jpa

I have the following for a multi-tenant application:

```
public class MultiTenantTransactionManager extends JpaTransactionManager {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MultiTenantTransactionManager.class);

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Inject
    private DefaultCurrentTenantResolver tenantResolver;

    @Override
    protected void doBegin(final Object transaction, final TransactionDefinition definition) {
        super.doBegin(transaction, definition);
        final EntityManagerHolder emHolder = (EntityManagerHolder) TransactionSynchronizationManager.getResource(getEntityManagerFactory());
        final EntityManager em = emHolder.getEntityManager();

        LOGGER.debug("Getting tenant-id");
        final Serializable tenantId = tenantResolver.getCurrentTenantId();
        if (tenantId != null) {
            em.setProperty("tenant-id", tenantId);
        } else {
            System.out.println("tenant-id is null");
        }
    }
}
```

This is registered as:

```
@Bean
public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new MultiTenantTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory()
            .getObject());
    return transactionManager;
}
```

When I do this to initialise some test data the doBegin method is called:

```
@PostConstruct
@Transactional
private void createDefaultUsers() {
    LOGGER.debug("Creating test users");

    Tenant tenant1 = new Tenant("Tenant 1");
    tenantRepository.saveAndFlush(tenant1);

    Tenant tenant2 = new Tenant("Tenant 2");
    tenantRepository.saveAndFlush(tenant2);

    User user1 = new User("username1", "User description", "admin");
    user1.setTenant(tenant1);

    User user2 = new User("username2", "User description", "admin");
    user2.setTenant(tenant2);

    userRepository.saveAndFlush(user1);
    userRepository.saveAndFlush(user2);
}
```

However when the following web service is called it is not

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/security/listUsers/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<List<User>> listAllUserv(@PathVariable("id") String id,
        @RequestHeader(value = "user_id", required = true) String user_uuid,
        @RequestHeader(value = "tenant_id", required = true) String tenant_uuid,
        @RequestHeader(value = "api_key", required = false) String apiKey, HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpSession httpSession) {

    if (tenant_uuid == null) {
        throw new UnauthorizedUserException();
    }

    TenantContext.setTenant(tenant_uuid);

    User user = userService.find(user_uuid);

    List<User> users = userService.findAll();

    if (users.isEmpty()) {
        return new ResponseEntity<List<User>>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND); 
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<List<User>>(users, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Code for service:

```
@Service("userService")
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Resource
    private UserRepository repository;

    @Override
    public User find(String uuid) {
        return repository.find(uuid);
    }

    @Override
    public void create(User user) {
        repository.saveAndFlush(user);
        return;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional  
    public List<User> findAll() {
        return repository.findAll();
    }
}
```

I don't understand what the difference is here between the initialising the data on server start up and calling a findAll() method via a web service; one sets the tenant-id on the entity manager and the other dosen't.  Both use the same repository etc

Any guidance very much appreciated

Comment: Does userService.findAll() have a `@Transactional` annotation?

Comment: Yes - I checked that - I will add the code...